# assigning a 2D array element to single pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to learn C. I am new to C programming. I have the following function.

```
/*dA would be a pointer to a 2D array*/
    void normalizeCols(float* dMu, float* dSigma, float* dB, float* dA, int n){
       int col, row;
       for(col=0; col < n; col++)
           /*Step 1: calculating mean*/
            float tempMu = 0.0; 
            dMu = &tempMu;
            for (row=0; row < n; row++){
                /*I am adding all the elements of the column*/
                dMu += *(*(dA+row)+col); //ERROR: operand of * must be a pointer
            }
            /*dividing dMu by number of dimension(square matrix)*/              
            dMu /= (float) n; //ERROR: expression must have arithmetic or enum type
            //More code here
       }
}
```

I am trying to find the mean of a column. I get those two errors that I have commented in the above snippet. How should I fix this?

Comment: Define more clearly what you mean by `dA += dA[row][col]`?

Comment: Do *what*? What are you trying to do? Are you trying to shift pointer `dA`? Or are you trying to add something to the value of `*dA`? There's at least two completely different ways ways to "fix" your code. Nobody knows which one is the correct one until you explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: think he's trying to add all the elements in the 2d array and find the mean.

Comment: I have changed my question which was wrong initially.

Comment: All other things aside, no single answer is going to breach the inescapable; you need to spend more time in C-pointer tutorials and texts. The *last* thing you should do when not *crystal-clear* on their usage is throw more code at the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that the matrices are square (i.e. the row-length is `n` which is also the number of rows), just do the addressing manually.

The inner loop then becomes:

```
       /*Step 1: calculating mean*/
       float tempMu = 0;
       for (row=0; row < n; row++){
           /*I am adding all the elements of the column*/
           tempMu += dA[col * n + row];
       }
       /*dividing dMu by number of dimension(square matrix)*/              
       tempMu /= (float) n;
```

Also, make the input arguments `const` to make it clearer, and switch `int` to `size_t`.

Of course, make sure you do the accesses in the proper order (either row-major or column-major) otherwise you'll get horrible cache thrashing.

Answer (score 1):

`(dA+row)` is a pointer, that is moved from `dA` a distance of `row` times the size of the type `dA` points to.

`*(dA+row)` gives the value of the location pointed by `(dA+row)` the pointer

`*(dA+row)+col` adds that value to `col`

`*(*(dA+row)+col)` is illegal because you can only de-reference a pointer which this is not.

Your `tempMu` should be:

```
tempMu += *(dA + row * n + col)
```

Comment: `dMu` in this case is also a pointer, so that's not correct either.

Answer (score 1):

On this line:

```
dMu += *(*(dA+row)+col); //ERROR: operand of * must be a pointer
```

Note that `dA` has type `float*`, therefore `*(dA+row)` is a `float`, `col` is promoted to a `float` in order to be added to this value, which is now in the outermost parentheses. When you dereference that with the leftmost `*`, you are attempting to dereference a `float`, which is the source of your error.

In order for that line to be type correct, `dA` would have to be `float**`, but you have other errors: `dMu` here, for example, is a pointer, which you are incrementing with `+=`, not a value. Did you mean `*dMu += ...` ?

Answer (score 0):

Not very clear what do you want to do. From the code I see that your are trying to make some "dangerous" operations with pointers.

```
            /I am adding all the elements of the column**/
            dMu += *(*(dA+row)+col);
```

You are not adding all the elements in the column but you are moving dMU pointer to another memory location.

```
*dMU += dA[row][col]
....
*dMu /= (float) n;
```

it should be correct.

Comment: It never even gets that far because he's doing a double dereference on a single-level pointer. The error message is coming from the leftmost `*` dereferencing a `float` in the outermost parentheses.